# In a pudding I eat, I give bread its potential

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> In a pudding I eat,
>   I give bread its potential,
>   In a trial I'm neat,
>   But in math I'm essential.

What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and great riddle!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are

> PROOF.

*In a pudding I eat*

> "[The proof of the pudding is in the eating.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_proof_of_the_pudding_is_in_the_eating)"

*I give bread its potential*

> [Proofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofing_(baking_technique)) is a step in the process of breadmaking which allows the bread to rise to its full potential.

*In a trial I'm neat*

> It's good to find proof of guilt or innocence in a trial.

*But in math I'm essential.*

> Proofs are certainly essential in maths!

Comment: I ***conjecture*** that this answer is not essential to mathematics!